# Undefined local variable or method `load_and_authorize_resource' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
NameError in HomeController#index 
undefined local variable or method `load_and_authorize_resource' for #<HomeController:0x3136e00>
Rails.root: D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/dynacan-master
```

I am new in Ruby On Rails, & I'm trying to implement the role in my app where I got the above error. please assist me out of this error & give me other alternate. ASAP

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have seen a similar error with the [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem

If you're using the gem [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), and you have `load_and_authorize_resource` in your `HomeController`, it's trying to load the `Home` model which doesn't exist. Instead, trying using `authorize_resource class: false`, so

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource class: false
  # rest of your code
end
```

For more information on using cancan on non RESTful controllers, see the [Wiki specifically about it](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers)

Hope this helps